# PHP7.3 GD headers Version and GD library Version don't match

Tags: php, gd

The php version is PHP 7.3.11-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli).

In `php -i`,

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD headers Version => 2.2.5
GD library Version => 2.1.1
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.6.1
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 8
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.54
WBMP Support => enabled
XPM Support => enabled
libXpm Version => 30411
XBM Support => enabled
WebP Support => enabled
```

The GD headers Version and GD library Version don't match. Is it correct?

Thank you.

Comment: They are two different packages, I don't think that this should affect you in any way

Comment: @delboy1978uk thank you. Do you know how to update GD library? Cheers.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.3-gd